# PHP: how to assert that an array contains a certain value?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, assert

I'm writing some unit tests using phpunit and I now want to assert that an array contains a certain value, but the only function I can find is assertArrayHasKey(). There is no assertArrayHasValue whatsoever.

So to be clear I want something like this:

```
$a = [5, 8, 16];
assertArrayHasValue(8, $a);
```

All tips are welcome!

Comment: Here is a list of assertion as well, maybe it will help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569369/list-of-all-phpunit-assertions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [test if array contains value using PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638220/test-if-array-contains-value-using-phpunit)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with function `assertContains()`

try this:

```
$a = [5, 8, 16];
$this->assertContains(8, $a);
```

[**ASSERT_CONTAINS**](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertContains)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ouzo goodies library](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies).

```
 $animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'pig'];
 Assert::thatArray($animals)->hasSize(3)->contains('cat');
```

There are a lot of interesting assertions that can be chained e.g.

```
Assert::thatArray($users)->onMethod('getAge')->containsOnly(35, 24);
```

See http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/documentation/tests.html#array-assertions